# Xamarin ICommand not firing

Tags: xaml, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I am new to MVVM and there is something and I am doing wrong in my Xamarin.Forms app.

Here's what I have in SessionsPage.xml

```
<Grid.Children>
    <Image Source="zero.jpg" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer
            Command="{Binding TapCommand}"
            CommandParameter="0" />
     </Image.GestureRecognizers>
```

I have an image linked to the Command "TapCommand".

In the constructor of this view, I added:

```
tapViewModel = new EasyScrum.Views.TapViewModel();
```

And the ViewModel class is:

```
public class TapViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    int taps = 0;
    ICommand tapCommand;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public TapViewModel()
    {
        // configure the TapCommand with a method
        tapCommand = new Command(OnTapped);
    }

    public ICommand TapCommand
    {
        get { return tapCommand; }
    }
    void OnTapped(object s)
    {
        taps++;
        Debug.WriteLine("parameter: " + s);
    }
    //region INotifyPropertyChanged code omitted
}
```

And the event is not firing, what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I answer myself.

My mistake was that I had to assign

this.BindingContext = new TapViewModel();